# Create array with dynamic key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a table in which dynamic rows are coming, so i don't know how many rows. Inside a td in the rows, there is some content that needs to be registered in an array on click of a button.

i need to create an array with that content, but it should be in this format:

```
array1 = [ row1:"", row2:"abc", row3:'', row4:'', row5:'xyz' ]
```

here, the row1...row5 comes dynamically based on the number of rows. By default the value of the rows can be '', thats fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: arrays can only have `0`... `N` (numeric) indexes

Comment: @Eddie not really, just array literals can not have properties.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ohh Nice to know :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array1 = [ row1:"", row2:"abc", row3:'', row4:'', row5:'xyz' ]
```

The above will not work as it it is incorrect syntax. What you can do is create an array of objects and use that instead.

```
array1 = [{row1:""},{row2:"abc"}];
```

Or, if the row number AND value are important, this may be a better structure:

```
array1 = [{rowId:1, value:""}, {rowId:2, value:"abc"}];
```

EDIT:

To create such a structure from an existing HTML Table, you can query for the rows and operate on each row to create the array.

```
// Get a reference to the table element
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
// Initialise empty array
var array = [];

// Query for all the tr elements of the table (rows)
table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(row, index){
    // For each row, extract value from the requried column
    var value = row.children[0].innerText; // Assuming the value to be added is in the first column (td)
    // Insert new object into array for this row
    array.push({rowId:index, value: value});
})

console.log(array); // array will be an array of our objects
```

Comment: yes, but how to make this dynamically baed on number of rows?

Comment: You can easily make this dynamically. But to answer accurately, I will need to understand your data source. From where are you creating this array? From HTML? from API?

Comment: @user3450590 I have updated my answer with a demo of creating it from a html table

Comment: agree with @Chirag Ravindra 
updated answer should be the choice.

Answer (score 0):

with a little modification in @Chirag Ravindra code

```
  // Get a reference to the table element
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
// Initialise empty array
var array = [];

// Query for all the tr elements of the table (rows)
    table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function(row, index){
// For each row, extract value from the requried column
var value = row.children[0].innerText; // Assuming the value to be added is in the first column (td)
// Insert new object into array for this row
array["row" + index] = value;
})

console.log(array); // array will be an array of our objects
```